# understanding how a lua function does work?

Tags: function, lua

I have a HTML project that uses mutiple lua scripts , I have big issue unterstanding the functionality of one function ( I'm new to lua)  :

........................

all the requires have been done and the paths are also defined

```
local fs = require "lfs"

local const = {}
for num = 1, 14 do
    const[num] = assert(
        dofile (const_path .. mkfilename(num)),
        "Failed to load constant configuration  ".. num ..".")
end




local function file_number()  --this is the function that causes me a headach
    local ci, co, num = ipairs(const)-- when I print num is 0 and ci,co are nil
    local vi, vo, _   = fs.dir(virt_path)--  what does _ mean here ? 
    local function vix(o)
        local file = vi(o)
        if file == nil then return nil end
        local number = file:match("^(%d+).lua$")
        if number == nil then return vix(o) end
        return tonumber(number)
    end
    local function iter(o, num)
        return ci(o.co, num) or vix(o.vo, num)---where is ci defined or impplemented 
    end
    return iter, {co=co, vo=vo}, num-- what 's the return value here ? 
end
```

the function works but I still don't understand why and how, I 'll be greatfull for any hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` is conventionally a throw-away variable.

In this case though it serves no purpose and could just as easily be left out entirely.

`ci` should be a function and `co` should be a table there.

Similarly (though I can't say for sure about `vo`) for `vi` and `vo`.

That function is constructing its own iterator using the iterator functions and state returns from the `ipairs` and `fs.dir` functions.

The line `return iter, {co=co, vo=vo}, num` is returning an interator function, a table for state, and the initial loop variable (`0` from the initial `ipairs` call).

When used in a loop that will loop over the values from `ci` and `vix`.

Comment: thanks for answer, when I use the function is works fine tell file number 17 that the order get lost, meaning I can get 21 before 16 and so on,,any idea why ? , ci and vi  has been only used once it the whole program, and only here

Comment: @Engine You are only guaranteed to get in-order numbers up until `14` (when `const` runs out) after that you are going to get directory entry order from `fs.dir` (since I don't believe that functions sorts).

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, it there a way to order the return value of fs.dir

Comment: @Engine Not in-place. For Windows `fs.dir` uses `_findfirst`/`_findnext` with whatever order that gets you (I don't know). On non-Windows `fs.dir` uses `readdir` which order is the directory entry order and isn't under your control. To get a specific order you would need to collect the entire output from `fs.dir` in a table and sort it (or use `scandir` and a sorting function but I don't know that luafilesystem exposes `scandir`).